# about test the sound recording function and View new created files in emulator

Tags: android

I am making a program for recording sound. I have completed the basic record functions and the interface. However, when I test it, I have no idea how to make use of the emulator to test if the program really work. Shall my computer equip with mic to test it?

Other than that, since my program will create a .3gp audio file in a designated path, but I have no idea how to view the folder in the emulator as i dont find something like a file manager in it... could anyone advice?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to do same thing, recording sound to a file. The created file should be displayed on the Music Player. In my case, it is appearing in the Music Player media contents list.